# Startup Manager does not affect boot order

Tags: dual-boot, startup

Running and editing the boot sequence with the startup Manager works fine - even saving these settings is done properly (I can check this with reopening the startup manager) - 
but after reboot - these settings are ignored.

Why ? How can I change that easily (for beginners) ???

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal an use the command `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the startup manager can only affect classic sysv-init-style daemons having start-stop scripts at `/etc/init.d/`.

Since most of these services are nowadays launched from ubuntus [upstart](/questions/tagged/upstart) replacement, upstart will actually calculate the dependencies itself and reorder them as it sees fit. So there is no simple answer to your question.